# Filter StreamBuilder snapshot data - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When the user enters `1st value` and `2nd value` and clicks the `submit` button, `StreamBuilder` should output the data between the values (**age filter**). How to do this?

Here is picture of display. and my code - below the picture

[image]

---

Full page code:

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final _firstTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _secondTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              // .orderBy("accountCreated")
              .where("activeStatus", isEqualTo: "active")
              // .where("uid", isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
                !streamSnapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _firstTextController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "from",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _secondTextController,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "to",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print("First value: ${_firstTextController.text}");
                            print(
                                "Second value: ${_secondTextController.text}");
                          },
                          child: const Text("Submit"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text(
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]["displayName"]);
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure it is the problem but you should not use ` FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              // .orderBy("accountCreated")
              .where("activeStatus", isEqualTo: "active")
              // .where("uid", isNotEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .snapshots(),` as your stream. Assign that to a variable in initState and then use the variable as your stream otherwise you are calling firestore every time your page rebuilds. Doesn't give you what you expect and costs you money.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int userLowerValue = 20;
  int userUpperValue = 60;

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getDataStream(int lower, int upper) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("age", isGreaterThan: lower)
        .where("age", isLessThan: upper)
        .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                int lower = 20;
                int upper = 60;
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Enter Filter Values"),
                      content: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: ListBody(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(labelText: "Lower Value"),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                lower = int.parse(value);
                              },
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(labelText: "Upper Value"),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                upper = int.parse(value);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text("Apply"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {
                              userLowerValue = lower;
                              userUpperValue = upper;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.filter))
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getDataStream(userLowerValue, userUpperValue),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
            if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||!streamSnapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (streamSnapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: CustomText(
                  text: "No results found",
                  size: 30,
                ),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]["displayName"]);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```